# Getting the full file path using a Node + Meteor + Electron file browser dialog

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, meteor, electron

This is a tricky one...

I have a Meteor web app that runs locally on a user's machine, either in the browser or packaged within an Electron app.

[https:github.com/lacymorrow/cinematic](http://https:github.com/lacymorrow/cinematic)

`cinematic.[js|html]` are the important files CSS selector `#directory-path`.

It uses local files on the machine, so technically the server and the client are the same machine, currently I require the user to explicitly know the file path of their Movies directory (ex: `/Users/username/Movies`), enter it on the client-facing side, and process the files using the `fs` NodeJS module.

I do as much inferring as possible, setting the default directory to the most likely location, but this just isn't good UI. I need a directory browser dialog.

## The Problem

Since the client view is HTML, a doesn't allow full access to the filesystem for security reasons.

`<input id="directory-path" type="file" name="files" webkitdirectory mozdirectory directory multiple />`

The values returned are a `FileList` with just the filenames, so I can process the video files, but don't have the full path to "open" them.

## Possible Solutions

- In Chome/WebKit I'm able to access a temporary URL

(**Downfall:** while the browser is open). There are no temp URLs in Firefox or Safari but Electron uses the same V8 JS engine in Canary so maybe that's an advantage.

- Detecting for Electron, serving an Electron dialog to app users, serving the path `input` for browser users.

(**Downfall:** Multi-ui; Requires connection between Electron-Meteor instead of just wrapping the app whole.

## Can anyone help me choose a reasonable approach to this?

Comment: just use the electron dialog https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/dialog/

Comment: That's what seems to be the "correct" route, but it's a little disappointing as it will no longer work through a browser instance (without electron) and also is going to require a good bit of electron boilerplate to get things working.

It becomes more complex than just running `electrify` or `electron-packager`